# Mono for Android - ZIP data compression

Tags: android, zip, compression, unzip

I'm trying to *decompress* some large file sent by a server and then, after some processing, send the file back *compressed* to the server, using always the ***ZIP*** format.

I want to know whether there is some zip compression/decompression utility method I can use within my code in order to accomplish the latter in a few lines.

I'm aware of solutions like *DotNetZip* or *SharpZipLib*, yet I would like to avoid the use of external libraries or having to keep track of extra .dll’s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is no compression/decompression utility method built-in in *Mono For Android* based on the ZIP format, so I ended up integrating ***SharpZipLib*** to my project and using the *InflaterInputStream.Read()* method, which works great for me, as referenced in the following link:

[How to use ICSharpCode.ZipLib with stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741591/how-to-use-icsharpcode-ziplib-with-stream)

Cheers!